# Carousel en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

alguien me puede decir en que falla el carousel se visualiza bien, pero no cambia al siguiente slider en el indicador.

```
<!-- TESTIMONIALS -->
    <section class="testimonial">

        <div class="testimonial-overlay">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div id="carousel-testimonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- INDICADORES -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="1"></li>

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="2"></li>

                            </ol>

                            <!--WRAPPER for SLIDES -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <!-- ITEM 1 -->
                                <div class="item active text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-01.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Daniel</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!-- ITEM 2 -->
                                <div class="item text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-02.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Raul Pole</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Marketing Manager,</span> Risko</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!-- ITEM 3 -->
                                <div class="item text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-03.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Jim So</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Assistan Manager,</span> Gidfo</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: Hola Caldeiro. No podemos depurar por tí. Muestranos lo que has detectado ya que pegar el código y decir "encontradme el fallo" es muy amplio. Mira [ask] y [mcve]  para más info. Crear un snippet de codigo (pulsando en `<>` dentro del editor de pregunta )  añadiendo bootstrap ayudará a reproducir tu problema y a ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: El problema es que a pesar de que las clases estan bien y no me he comido ninguna letra ni nada, el carousel no cambia no se mueve del primer slider aunque le des a siguiente/anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He copiado tal cual tu código y le he añadido las librerías y a mi me funciona bien. No salen las flechas del slider pero si que cambia.

El error podría ser que te falta ra importar el `css` o el `js`.

Te dejo el resultado.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- TESTIMONIALS -->
    <section class="testimonial">

        <div class="testimonial-overlay">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <div id="carousel-testimonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- INDICADORES -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="1"></li>

                                <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="2"></li>

                            </ol>

                            <!--WRAPPER for SLIDES -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <!-- ITEM 1 -->
                                <div class="item active text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-01.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Daniel</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!-- ITEM 2 -->
                                <div class="item text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-02.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Raul Pole</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Marketing Manager,</span> Risko</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!-- ITEM 3 -->
                                <div class="item text-center">

                                    <img src="images/client-03.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">

                                    <div class="testimonial-caption">

                                        <h2>Jim So</h2>

                                        <h4><span>Assistan Manager,</span> Gidfo</h4>

                                        <p>"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: Puede ser porque acabo de hacer la navbar y en responsive no se desplega el menu asi que me debe faltas por importar algo..